# reason of splitting theme files to multiple files

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, theme-options

I can create my theme without splitting it into separate files.  Why do theme developers split WordPress theme into a few single files like header.php sidebar.php and etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that for child themes. If you have a separate `header.php` a child theme can use its own `header.php` and override the parent theme’s file. Plus, `header.php` and `footer.php` are used in `wp-signup.php`.

Another reason is readability: Putting all the code for a theme into just one file gets very messy very fast.

A use case for a compact theme is testing and debugging: My [Mini Theme](https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme) uses just `index.php` and `comments.php` for output. Whenever a plugin doesn’t do what I expected I use that theme to be sure it is not a theme issue.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the platform (WordPress, Joomla!, Drupal) or the language (PHP, C++, VB) it's pretty much accepted/standard practice to break out code in to functional units. This includes not only functions and classes, but files as well.

As @Toscho points out:

1. The code is used in multiple places.
2. It improves readability.

It also makes it easier to:

1. Maintain your code.
2. Reuse it in other areas.
3. Organize it in to manageable chunks/blocks.
4. Work in a team environment.
5. ...

The list could go on for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Both @toscho's and @stephen's answers good answers, and I upvoted them, but also remember that WordPress looks for particular template files depending upon context. For example, a file named `category.php` will be used automatically for category archives. `author.php` will be used for author archives. If you choose not to use [the built in template architecture](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) you will have to build those switches (or at least the ones you want) into your code, which would be tedious and redundant.

Comment: You don’t need any of those switches depending on the styles you are using.

Comment: It is true that you might not need any of the template hierarchy functionality. That is why I said, "or at least the ones you want".